# Kafka network IO metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

Using JMX server for monitoring Kafka metrics I want to get all network IO for each broker(node). Using MBeans `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=BytesInPerSec` and `kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=BytesOutPerSec` I can get network IO just when some data are produced to or consume from a broker, but we know there is some network IO between brokers for replication, metadata, connecting to Zookeeper and so on. In my Kafka cluster, each node network IO is about 6kb, while no data is consumed or produced. Is there any Kafka metrics to monitor network IO aside from data produced or consumed?

Answer (score 1):

Under `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RequestsPerSec` you find counters for all the request types including `Fetch` and `FetchFollower` issued even when there is no produce/consume traffic to the cluster.

Comment: Yes, this is the request number per second, but I want to get for example bytesIn/Out per second for `Fetch` and `FetchFollower`

Comment: I don't think those are metrics that are exposed so you would probably have to figure out the size of such requests and multiply by the rate yourself.

Answer (score -2):

You can check the produced or consumed rate either through enabling jmx at producer and consumer or at broker , both are possible.

In broker there are several metrics for n/w and request rates , for example

- BrokerTopicMetrics.topic.{topic}.BytesInPerSec
- BrokerTopicMetrics.topic.{topic}.BytesOutPerSec

You can check the jmx metrics exposed in the below kafka doc, although this is not exhaustive , if you want to see all the metrics ,you can enable the jmx on broker/producer/consumer and check through VisualVM or any other tool

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html

Comment: I mentioned in the post that `BytesInPerSec` and `BytesOutPerSec` is just for produced or consumed data, in addition, I want inter-broker network IO.

Comment: You will have BytesInPerSec and BytesOutPerSec per broker , BytesInPerSec is aggregated of all the requests , you can also check FetchFollower metrics